# Using computer vision to identify color of cars and change them

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am taking a course on computer vision.

Project: Identify the color of the car and change it. 
For example: take a picture of a red Honda civic on the driveway, change that red paint color into a blue color. Should ignore changing the colors of the ground/lawn etc.

Now I don't know if my approach is the best but I have been looking into how to approach this problem

Approach:

1. Design a CNN that will detect and classify the image of the car within the picture.
2. Design a separate CNN classifier that will detect and classify the color of the car and connect this with the CNN
3. Connect the two CNN together. Creating a neural network where one CNN will do patch wise detection of the color while the second CNN classifies the image and the car within.
4. Create a GAN-like network that takes the color of the car. If the color of the car is already blue nothing happens, but if the color of the car is red then the GAN will change the color of the car to blue.

Are there different ways to approach this problem?

I want to figure out this problem on my own, but please point me in the right direction

Comment: Please read [ask] and [tour]. If you have any specific questions about *programming* you're welcome to ask here.

Comment: That said, your approach seems way over the top for an extra credit project. I'd be very surprised if you get all of that to work. Note that a CNN to detect the car within the picture will require lots and lots of training data, meaning you'll be sitting and manually drawing car outlines full-time for weeks. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks Chris for your response. I guess I will find another way to approach this problem then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your approach can get the job done but looks like an overkill to train several networks just to change the color.

A rather simpler approach can be be to try to segment the car out of the image. Basically a refined version of your step 1. Once you have a mask for the car changing the color is pretty easy using opencv. 
For segmenting the car you can look into https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN. Use the pre-trained version.

Another way is to directly train a GAN to do the whole thing without going through the intermediary steps. Take a look at https://junyanz.github.io/CycleGAN/.

Comment: Hey these two are amazing ideas. I will look into i and come back to you on it. Thank you so much for helping an commenting.